# Objective-C – NSDateFormatter dateFromString ignore time

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsdateformatter

If I'm not interested in the time can I ignore it? I.e I have a date string that looks like this `@"2012-12-19T14:00:00"` but I'm only interested in getting the date (2012-12-19) but if I set `NSDateFormatter` like `[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];` it will return me a nil `NSDate`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An NSDate object will always contain a time component as well, as it is representing a point in time — from this perspective one could argue the name NSDate is misleading.

You should create a date formatter for creating dates from string, set the time to the start of the day and use a second date formatter to output the date without time component.

```
NSString *dateString = @"2012-12-19T14:00:00";

NSDateFormatter *inputFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[inputFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"];

NSDateFormatter *outputFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[outputFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
[outputFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];

NSDate *date = [inputFormatter dateFromString:dateString];

//this will set date's time components to 00:00
[[NSCalendar currentCalendar] rangeOfUnit:NSDayCalendarUnit
                                startDate:&date
                                 interval:NULL
                                  forDate:date];

NSString *outputString = [outputFormatter stringFromDate:date];

NSLog(@"%@", outputString);
```

results in

```
19.12.12
```

while the format — as it is chosen by styling — will be dependent of your environment locale

Comment: I ended up doing: `NSString *event = [event substringToIndex:10]; //to strip out the time` `[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];` `NSDate *eventDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:event];` is that an OK solution?

Comment: I think this is the maximum ugly solution possible. You should treat dates and times as NSDates. also this wont give you any flexibility for localization and timezone handling.

Comment: Do you really need to set the time component to `00:00`?  Couldn't you just leave the TimeStyle as `NoStyle` and be done with it?

Comment: @DaveDeLong — probably, depends on what it is meant to use for.

Answer (score -2):

all date string returns 10 characters for the date, what i mean is the date of todayy will be 2012-11-19

you can easily substring the date and use it as you want:

Example :

```
    NSString* newDate = @"";
    newDate = [[NSDate date]substringToIndex:10];
```

the out put will be : `2012-11-19`

Comment: I see a crash down the road…